# Struggling with pygame collisions

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm writing some code for a pygame sonic clone and I'm struggling with tile collisions. All sorts of bugs keep arising. For instance, one bug is when the player collides with the tile's rectangle it looks like they're vibrating. My movement involves using vectors and some of my values are floats. I think this is the issue since floats can cause all sorts of weird bugs. Either way, what do you think? Is it possible to have proper collisions?

**Main.py**

```
from settings import *
from sprites import *
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True


window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# initialise camera
camera = Camera(WIDTH, HEIGHT)


# player sprites
s = Sonic()
player = pygame.sprite.Group()

# floor sprites
ground = Ground(0, HEIGHT - 50, GROUND)
floor = pygame.sprite.Group()
floor.add(ground)

# platform sprites

platforms = [Platform(WIDTH + 200, HEIGHT - 100, SMALL)]

plats = pygame.sprite.Group()

platx = 100 

platy = 50


for i in platforms:
    plats.add(i)
    

# all sprites
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add(s)
sprites.add(plats)
sprites.add(ground)

# TODO: figure out a way to blit the camera (done)

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # update
    if s.vel.y > 0:
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(s, floor, False)

        if collisions:
            for collision in collisions:
                # TODO: create different classes of platforms each with their own collision properties (done)
                if s.pos.y > collision.rect.top: 
                    s.vel.y = (s.vel.y - 0.6)
                    s.pos.y = collision.rect.top
                    
                
    
    # TODO: figure out how to reset x vel when jumping
    
    if s.vel.x > 0:
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(s, plats, False)
        
        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if s.pos.x > hit.rect.left and s.pos.x < hit.rect.right:
                    s.vel.x = 0
                    s.pos.x = (hit.rect.left - 30)
                    
    if s.vel.x < 0:
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(s, plats, False)

        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if s.pos.x < hit.rect.right and s.pos.x > hit.rect.left:
                    s.vel.x = 0
                    s.pos.x = (hit.rect.right + 30)
    
    if s.vel.y > 0:
        s.vel.x = 0
        s.vel.y = 0
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(s, plats, False)

        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if s.pos.y > hit.rect.top:
                    s.vel.y = 0
                    s.pos.y = hit.rect.top
    
    if s.vel.y < 0:
        if s.vel.x > 0 and s.vel.x < 0:
            s.vel.x = 0
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(s, plats, False)

        if hits:
            for hit in hits:
                if s.pos.y < hit.rect.bottom:
                    s.vel.x = 0
                    s.vel.y = 0
                    s.pos.y = hit.rect.bottom
    


                
                # if s.vel.x < 0:
                #     s.rect.left = hits[0].rect.right
                #     s.vel.x = 0
                # if s.vel.y < 0:
                #     s.rect.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
                #     s.vel.y = 0
                # if s.vel.y > 0:
                #     s.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top
                #     s.vel.y = 0
            

    
        
    # if s.pos.x > WIDTH:
    #     for plat in plats.sprites():
    #         plat.rect.x -= max(abs(s.vel.x), 2)
    #         # set locations for each platform
    #         # set the camera to follow sonic so that he doesn't disappear off the screen
    #         print("poop")

    print(s.vel)
    
    sprites.update()
    camera.update(s)

    # draw
    window.fill(BLACK)
    
    for sprite in sprites:
        window.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
    
    

#TODO: Create a way to dynamically generate platforms

    # double buffering 
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**sprites.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import *

vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Sonic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 51)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2 , HEIGHT - 51)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.last_update = 0
        self.time_passed = 0
        

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, GRAVITY)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -ACCEL - 2
            self.faster()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = ACCEL
            self.faster()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.acc.y = -ACCEL
                    
       
       # friction check
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRICTION
        if self.vel.x < -2:
            self.vel.x = -2

       # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        # if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
        #     self.pos.x = 0
        # if self.pos.x < 0:
        #     self.pos.x = WIDTH

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    # sonic speed feature - get faster after running for x amount of time
    def faster(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > FASTER_TIME:
            self.time_passed += (now - self.last_update)
            self.acc.x /= 0.5 # player becomes 50% faster
            if self.time_passed >= 3000:
                self.acc.x /= 0.75
            
class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, plat):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((GROUND))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, plat):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((plat))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x 
        self.rect.y = y

# creates a camera that follows the player
class Camera():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    
    # set the camera's focus - offset then applied to above Rect
    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft) # move by current camera's (0, 0) and returns a new rect
    
    # update the camera's position
    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.x + int(WIDTH / 2) # keeps player centered
        y = -target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT - 50) # keeps player centered
 
        x = min(0, x) # ensure camera doesn't go off the screen
        y = min(0, y)

        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

**settings.py**

```
# game properties
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# physics
GRAVITY = 0.2
ACCEL = 1
FRICTION = -0.12
FASTER_TIME = 2000

# Platform properties
SMALL = (100, 50)
MEDIUM = (20000, 200)
GROUND = (100000, 100)

# Player properties
HALF_P_WIDTH = 25
PREVIOUS_POS = [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve jittering, you need to do three things:

1. Move the player and update the objects (`sprites.update()`) before the collision test.
2. Update the `rect` attribute when a collision is detected and the `pos` attribute has changed:
3. Set `vel.y` to 0, when the player stands on the ground or on a platform

e.g.:

```py
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    sprites.update()                              # 1. update

    if s.vel.y > 0:
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(s, floor, False)
        for collision in collisions:
            if s.pos.y > collision.rect.top: 
                s.pos.y = collision.rect.top
                s.rect.bottom = s.pos.y           # 2. set rect.bottom = s.pos.y
                s.vel.y = 0                       # 3. set vel.y = 0

    
    # [...]

    camera.update(s)

    # draw
    window.fill(BLACK)
    
    for sprite in sprites:
        window.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more thing, it seems that the player is still moving even though they're colliding with the platform and it's making it nearly impossible to do proper collisions. For instance, if the player collides with the top they are immediately blitted to either side. Or if they are colliding with the side they are blitted onto either top. How would you handle that?

Comment: *"it's making it nearly impossible to do proper collisions."* - In fact collision is very easy. Just clean up your code. You have asked multiple questions. This is not intended. I have and will only answer one of them. Even more when a comment starts with "One more thing [...]", I'm off. The comment section is not intended to ask follow up questions. If you have a new questions. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).